# Maximum subset of [1,899] that contains no two disjoint length 3 arithmetic progressions with same gap length

Tags: combinatorics

Let X be a subset of [1,899]. What is the maximum size $X$ can have if $X$ contains no two disjoint arithmetic progressions of length 3 and same gap between members?

For example: 1,3,5 and 2,4,6 are progressions of length 3, they are disjoint and they have the same gap length.

1,3,5 and 6,7,8 fails on the gap length requirement but meets the length and disjointness requirement.

Comment: Do you mean "how many possible sets of six numbers such that ..." are there?

Comment: Looks more like he means "What is the least $M$ so that, if we pick any $M$ number set $A$ from $[100,199]$, there must be two disjoint AP's each length 3 with same length in the set $A.$

Comment: In my last comment it should be to pick the M numbers from [100,999]. I also think the OP should make it more clear by a rephrasing along the lines of the last comment, or at least adjust to "must be picked so that there is guaranteed to be two disjoint ..."

Comment: As far as I know, questions of the type "How many numbers from interval $I$ must be picked so that they contain a pattern $P$" practically never yield explicit answers (cf. Ramsey Theorem, van der Waerden Theorem, etc.). I would be very strongly surpsised if there was an explicit answer to the above question. However, I'm more hopeful about an asymptotic statement along similar lines.

Comment: @Feanor How can the answer not be explicit if I am asking for a specific case. The answer is a unique integer.

Comment: @Omnitic: Maybe I didn't phrase my thought precisely. Of course, the explicit number exists. However, I doubt that we will manage to find it with our limited means, so I would be surprised is someone gave this explicit answer.

Comment: A computer program could find the number, but may require too much time or memory. For any given subset size $a$ we could try all those subsets and see if any are "doubly 3AP free". If one is found we know our desired number is greater than $a$, and then go on to try $a+1$.

Comment: Why is it unclear, please tell me.

Comment: It should be "and that there is no set *smaller* than $X$ having the saqme property. Also the phrase "doubly arithmetic sequence" is undefined. Go back to "two disjoint arithmetic sequences of length 3 with the same difference".

Comment: I think this is clearer, I hope it is clear now.